# I can't get satellite imagery as a background in geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I have multiple shapefiles that I am trying to map in geopandas, but I can't get aerial/satellite imagery as a background image. These are very zoomed in shapefiles, and probably cover less than half a mile square. These are in Iowa in the United States.

Here is my code.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import fiona, os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import pandas as pd 
import contextily as ctx

boundary = gpd.read_file(boundaryFile)
sample_data = gpd.read_file(sampleFile)
yieldData = gpd.read_file(yieldFile)
filesList = [boundary, sample_data, yieldData]

for i in filesList:
    i.set_crs(epsg=3857, inplace=True)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = yieldData.plot()
ctx.add_basemap(ax, source=ctx.providers.Esri.WorldImagery)
```

I am getting a ValueError: The inferred zoom level of 34 is not valid for the current tile provider. This can indicate that the extent of your figure is wrong (e.g. too small extent, or in the wrong coordinate reference system)

Thanks for your help

Comment: I guess you have mixed up projections. Maybe you wanted `to_crs` instead of `set_crs`?

Comment: I tried doing as you suggested, but it wouldn't let me. I had to set _crs first and then I could use to_crs. However, that didn't fix my problem if I did both, and I still go the same error.

Comment: You'll have to show us your data to debug this. I still think it is a projection mix up, that you are setting an incorrect one.